# How to get part of path using linux commands

Tags: bash, path, get, pwd

Need get part of path, for example
    "/home/server/folder1/rev.1111/bin"
Needed part is "rev.1111"
I`ll try to parse by PWD & grep commands, but I am newbie on linux and I cant do this.

Comment: being a newbie does not mean you can not do anything before asking a question like this, your first stop should be http://www.gnu.org instead of here

Answer (score 14):

```
pwd | awk -F/ '{print $(NF-1)}'
```

Comment: This works great, thank you. You can also do it the otherway to piece together the front part of the path '{ print $1/$2/$3 }' etc.

Answer (score 14):

Using the basename & dirname commands:

```
basename $(dirname $(pwd))
```